# Proper way to turn off firebase listeners?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following listener:

```
 firebaseDB.ref(`organizations/${org_id}/requests`)
        .orderByChild('employee_id')
        .equalTo(employee_id)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
            // do some stuff
        })
```

I always turn it off using the above query:

```
firebaseDB.ref(`organizations/${org_id}/requests`)
            .orderByChild('employee_id')
            .equalTo(employee_id)
            .off()
```

but I was wondering if it is ok to turn it off in a parent node such as organization or request?, assuming I'm not listening to anything else.

```
firebase.ref(`organization/${org_Id}`).off()
```

or

```
firebaseDB.ref(`organizations/${org_id}/requests`).off()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should use the same Query object that was originally used to add the listener.